# How to clear previously selected checkbox values in bootstrap multiselect list box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, listbox-control

I am using bootstrap multiselect js for one of my requriement.
    It is working fine loading list box options , displaying seleted 3 
    options everything fine,But on the same page i have one radiobutton option. 
    When user selects that radiobutton already selected bootstrapmulti selection 
    will uncheck all the options and that above text what it is showing the selcted 
    options also need to be clear and it should show nonselected.
    But for me i am able to unchek all previous selected listbox options,
    but that above text is not.

****Mycode****

```
 $("#worldid").click(function() // radiobutton id
 {
    $(".multiselectboxclass").prop("checked",false); // added one class and unchekcing successfully
    $("#listboxA").html('<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" type="button">Select States <b class="caret"></b></button>');
 });
```

**"listboxA"** is the id of the div where multiselect options will display.

But here after selecting radio button "nonselected" is displaying, 
but no listbox options or chekboxes.

Comment: Can some body please answer to this question... :(

Comment: You could create a fiddle to make things clearer, but I suppose that you used the same name / id for your checkbox and radiobuttons.